# How do I "select null as "Column" Using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq

How do I select NULL as a column option in linq.

My sql would read.

```
Select field1, field2, field3, null as "null", field4 
from table1
```

My linq query would be:

```
from t in table1
select new { t.field1, t.field2, t.field3, null as "null", t.field4}
```

The error generated by visual studio is:

> Cannot assign  to anonymous type property

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drop the `as "null"` and name the parameter, casting the `null` to its type:

```
from t in table1
select new { t.field1, t.field2, t.field3, someField = (string)null, t.field4}
```